# Get first element of list in EL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Is there any possibility to get only the first element from list in view?

```
 <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
     <h3>${product.name}</h3>
 </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're sure there is at least one element, you could write:

```
<c:set var="first" value="${products[0]}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works ;)